# Handling data modification in SAP from web service in XML

Tags: xml, abap, sap-pi

I am developing a creation/modification web service in SAP.
Creation is OK but for modification the calling system has a standard:

- if they send a tag that's filled with a value: modify field in SAP
- if the tag is empty: clear field in SAP
- if any tag is not present: do nothing to the corresponding field

In SAP, I am in a class and see a simple structure of fields. No view of the XML.
In addition, between me and other system is SAP-PI, a middleware.
Apparently, PI always sends all tags.
So how do I detect the three states?

For now our solution is PI sends me all tags and for those that he detects as "present" he adds an attribute is_present='X' to the tag.
With this all the fields become structures with two fields: CONTENT, IS_PRESENT.

Before I rework my code, does anybody know if there is another way to do this?

Comment: Are you using abap proxy (sproxy) or a function module (exposed as web service)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a best practice to recognize whether a field is blank because its value is blank or the corresponding XML tag is missing.

### Precondition: PI must not arbitrarily add missing tags

Because

> Apparently, PI always sends all tags

is generally false. I don't know if your PI mapping adds missing tags for some reason but generally speaking PI definitely has the ability keep a tag absent in the xml resulted after the conversion.

If your PI mapping *must* add those missing tags or you can't change it, you can stop reading further.

Assuming you have the following situation:

```
[Source xml] -> PI -> [Converted xml] -> ECC or S/4
```

And source xml contains

```
<root>
<field1>changed value</field1>
<field2></field2> <!-- value to be cleared -->
<!--
    <field3> is missing in this particular message
-->
</root>
```

The message resulting after the PI conversion should be like

```
<root_proxy>
<field1>changed value</field1>
<field2>value to be cleared</field2>
<!--
    <field3> is missing in this particular message
-->
</root_proxy>
```

And **not**

```
<root_proxy>
<field1>changed value</field1>
<field2></field2> <!-- value to be cleared -->
<field3></field3> <!-- tag added by PI -->
</root_proxy>
```

### At Backend side

In the input data of your inbound method you'll find some fields called `CONTEXT` (`PRXCTRLTAB` type). You have one `CONTEXT` for every structure, in case of deep structures.

In this table you can find the field names where XML is missing. Example:

```
loop at input-root_proxy-context into data(ls_context). " cycle through all input fields
  case ls_context-value.
  when sai_ctrl_none.    " handle missing xml tag
  when sai_ctrl_initial. " handle fields with initial value
  endcase.
endloop.
```

To activate this feature implement the `CONSTRUCTOR` of your ABAP Proxy class and set `SET_EXTENDED_XML_HANDLING = 'X'`. For example:

```
DATA:  
  lo_context   TYPE REF TO if_ws_server_context,
  lo_protocol TYPE REF TO if_wsprotocol_payload.

lo_context   = cl_proxy_access=>get_server_context( ).
lo_protocol = lo_context->get_protocol( if_wsprotocol=>payload ).
lo_protocol->set_extended_xml_handling( abap_true ).
```

Source: [Activating Extended XML Handling](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_740/684cffda9cbc4187ad7dad790b03b983/48591b845e024bb9e10000000a42189b.html?locale=en-US)

Comment: Hi and thanks for all this info.

Comment: `Precondition: PI must not arbitrarily add missing tags` agree with Manuel, it's better to correct the PI mapping than to reinvent the wheel on backend side

Comment: This is the solution (activating extended XML handling)  on ABAP backend . 
If you need to base decisions on  wasa field sent or not.  Tick.
Be warned, the performance AND size implications are serious.  Unfortunately I dont recall just how much slowly and how much more memory it uses , but it was very significant.  Orders of magnitude worse.  I had to turn it off and find a different solution.
If you you have a low volume or small data interface, you dont care.  If you have high volumes or very large documents, you may want to stress test the interface.